# using Ajax with 3 consecutive dependable drop down lists

Tags: php, javascript, mysql, ajax, drop-down-menu

peace be with you All, i am new to using Ajax , the issue is, i am having 3 drop down lists connected to a database, the first one is "name" and the second one is "age" and the third one is "country"! so, i have connected to the database, and retrieved data from it in the first list "name" and then using Ajax, i have successfully retrieved matching data after selecting any option of first list and put them into the second list called "age", the problem is that when i use a very exact same way with the second list called "age" to retrieve matching data into third list called "country" it doesn't work! so please help me cuz, i am using this example to learn Ajax and then apply on a larger real project! here is the code :- firstly, the home.php page:-

```
<?php
include "config.php";
?>
<html> 
<head> 
<script type="text/javascript">
function agematch() {
 if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
  xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
} 
 else {
 xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject('Microsoft.XMLHTTP');
 }

xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
  if(xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200) {

  document.getElementById('age').innerHTML = xmlhttp.responseText;
  }

} 
xmlhttp.open('GET', 'connection.inc.php?name='+document.ajax.name.value, true );
xmlhttp.send();

}

function countrymatch() {
 if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
  xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
} 
 else {
 xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject('Microsoft.XMLHTTP');
 }

xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
  if(xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200) {

  document.getElementById('country').innerHTML = xmlhttp.responseText;
  }

} 
xmlhttp.open('GET', 'country.inc.php?age='+document.ajax.age.value, true );
xmlhttp.send();

}

</script>
</head>
<body> 
<form id="ajax" name="ajax" > 
Choose your name : <select name="name" id="name" select="selected"  onchange="agematch();"> <option>  </option> 
 <?php

   $query = "SELECT DISTINCT name FROM info";
   $result = mysql_query($query);
   while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){
   echo"<option  value ='".$row[0]."'> '".@$row[0]."'</option>";
                                }   
 ?>
</select>
Age : <select id="age" name="age" onchange="countrymatch();">  </select>
country : <select id="country" name="country"> <option> </option> </select>

</form>
</body>
</html>
```

now, the page for first Ajax call :-

```
<?php
include "config.php";
echo " <option>  </option> " ;
if(isset( $_GET['name']) ) {
  @$name = $_GET['name'];
  }

  $query = "SELECT age FROM info WHERE name = '".@$name."' "; 
  $result = mysql_query($query);
    while ($query_row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {

      echo " <option  value ='".$query_row[0]."'> $query_row[0]</option> ";
      }

 ?>
```

Now, with the page for the second Ajax call for the third drop menu :-

```
<?php
include "config.php"; 

  if (isset( $_GET['age']) ) {
     @$age=$_GET['age'];
   }     

  $query = "SELECT country FROM info WHERE name='".@$name."' AND age='".@$age."'  ";
  $result= mysql_query($query);
  while  ($query_row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {

   echo " <option value = '".$query_row[0]."'> $query_row[0] </option> ";

  }

 ?>
```

so as you see, here is the code, and of course i am connected to the database through a page called "config.php", so i want you to help me to solve this issue and retrieve the data from database into the third drop down list "country". Thanks in Advance!

Comment: I'd recommened you start using a library like jQuery for javascript, will make your life much easier.

Comment: Hi, in the Network tab of Chrome's console, have you checked if the AJAX requests done are passing the expected parameters? Also, a suggestion: instead of writing your own code to manage AJAX requests, you could use jQuery that handles errors and it's cross-browser tested.

Comment: thanks everybody, question answered

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not passing `name` in the second call.

Replace

`xmlhttp.open('GET', 'country.inc.php?age='+document.ajax.age.value, true );`

with

`xmlhttp.open('GET', 'country.inc.php?age='+document.ajax.age.value+'&name='+document.ajax.name.value, true );`

Hope that helps.

Comment: Thank you forever man :D, i am really thankful for your help :)